# Spacing with tilde

Tags: spacing, tilde

When I type

```
$i\tilde{=} j$
```

the spacing is less than

```
$i=j$
```

i.e. the `i`, `\tilde{=}`, and `j` all appear next to each other without space. How can I change it back to normal spacing?

Comment: You probably want `\cong` instead of `\tilde{=}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction `\tilde{=}` makes an “accent atom”, which is considered just like a letter (“ordinary atom”).

Using `$i\mathrel{\tilde{=}}j$` would solve the spacing problem, but the correct symbol is `\cong`:

```
$i \cong j$
```

Comment: How do you know that kind of stuff? :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Being one of the world's leading experts on TeX/LaTeX is a tough job, but someone's got to do it.  egreg fills those shoes.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner My first use of `\cong` was possibly around 1986